# Update table using different random values for each update row

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, random

I want to update random 20% values of a table in Postgres, I want to assign for this attribute the old attribute + a random number with specific limits, and I want that for each row this random number must be different.

I am currently doing this:

```
update tab_ex
set val = (SELECT val + (SELECT random()*2000 FROM generate_series(20,2000) LIMIT 1))
where id in (select id from tab_ex order by random() limit (select count(*)*0.2 from tab_ex));
```

and it is updating 20% of my table however it is updating with a specific random number for every row instead of changing this random number for each update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this problem in other databases, where a subquery gets "optimized away" even though it has a volatile function in it.  That may be happening here.  One possibility is to remove the subquery:

```
update tab_ex
    set val = val + random() * 2000
    where id in (select id
                 from tab_ex
                 order by random()
                 limit (select count(*)*0.2 from tab_ex)
                );
```

This should re-run `random()` for every row being updated.

Comment: It is because the internal subquery `SELECT random()*2000 FROM generate_series(20,2000) LIMIT 1` is not depending on the updating row data. Changing it to `SELECT random()*2000 + val FROM generate_series(20,2000) LIMIT 1` for example also solves the problem.

Comment: @Abelisto . . . But why would you use a subquery  when one is not necessary?

Comment: I not using subquery and I don't know the OP's logic at this point. I just explain "why" and "how".